# Why is this program allocating more memory than necessary?

Tags: c, malloc

I am writing a program in C that needs to read from stdin. I don't want it to allocate more memory than necessary, so I am reading the input in chunks, `malloc`ing more memory each time a new chunk is read.

Here is the code (the `allocd` variable is just for tracking how much memory it has allocated):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZ 20

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *str = malloc(1), *p = NULL;
    *str = '\0';
    char buf[SIZ];
    int bufs = 0;
    int allocd = 0;

    while (p = fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin))
    {
        /* grow str */
        str = realloc(str, bufs * SIZ + SIZ);
        allocd = bufs * SIZ + SIZ;
        strcat(str, buf);
        bufs++;

        if (!p)
            break;
    }

    printf("ALLOC'D: %i", allocd);

    free(str);
}
```

For testing, I have a file called `file.txt`, which has 966 characters, as you can see when I use `wc`:

```
$ wc -m file.txt
966 file.txt
```

The problem is that my program seems to be allocating far more bytes of memory than there are characters in the file, as you can see:

```
$ ./code <file.txt
ALLOC'D: 1680
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What's the output of `wc -c file.txt`?

Comment: @klutt same output as `wc -m file.txt`.

Comment: It should be pretty easy to step through this code in a debugger and find out more about what's going on.

Comment: Why `fgets`instead of `read`? `fgets`only reads one line and I don't think your problem is related to lines

Comment: You are allocating for the size of the buffer, not the actual length of each string.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Suppose one line has length 10 (including the newline). You need to allocate 10 more bytes, but you are allocating `SIZ` more bytes, 20.

Comment: If on Linux, consider using [getline(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or [readline(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html). With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile your code using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) to understand its behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're allocating a new chunk of memory for each *line* you (attempt to) read regardless of how long the line actually is. I'd argue `fgets` is the wrong tool here, that what you want is [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) instead:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZ 20

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *str = malloc(1);
    *str = '\0';
    char buf[SIZ];
    int allocd = 0;

    int p;

    // Note: fread() returns size_t number of records read, NOT a char*
    while ((p = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), stdin)))
    {
        str = realloc(str, allocd + p + 1);

        // Concatenate the buffer
        memcpy(str + allocd, buf, p);

        allocd += p;
    }

    str[allocd + 1] = 0;

    printf("ALLOC'D: %i", allocd);

    free(str);
}
```

Comment: @ikegami Good improvements. This could be refactored considerably, but this is at least a place to start.

Comment: [Cleanups](https://pastebin.com/ejq9BpNe) (Sorry, there were mistakes in earlier one). None of those `int` makes sense.

Comment: Based on both of your solutions, I now have [something that works](https://pastebin.com/XMT5rjbg), but I still don't fully understand what was going wrong before. What was `fgets` doing that was causing the problem?

Comment: @AJ-Williams1 `fgets()` wasn't causing a problem in itself. You needed `strlen(buf)` more bytes of memory, but you were allocating `SIZ` more byes.

Comment: So `buf` wasn't filled, but I was allocating the full space that `buf` had allocated for it? Just confirming, because I want to understand for the future.

Comment: Yes. If the line had say 12 bytes, you were allocating 20, which is 20 - 12 = 8 bytes more than needed. The `strcat()` only copies up to the length of the data, not its buffer (it does not even know the buffer size, but it detects the end of the string data).

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for your help, explanations, and patience. I understand now what my problem was, and hopefully I can avoid making the same mistake in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> I am writing a program in C that needs to read from stdin. I don't want it to allocate more memory than necessary, so I am reading the input in chunks, mallocing more memory each time a new chunk is read.

Well, your savings intentions are good idea for a programmer, but you are wrong in the savings, because you are not taking into account many things that are hidden to you, but necessary to support an efficient implementation to `malloc`.

- The first is that malloc needs to associate extra memory to the block you request, in order to maintain the heap and don't get messed up with the allocation tasks.  This means that, let's say that the structure it associates to each bunch of memory you request be a constant and let's say that it is 8 bytes large, the `malloc(1)` will need to use `8bytes + 1` (this last the one you requested) to manage your task.  This means that if you make a million such allocations you will have 1 million bytes allocated in your accountability, but you will be wasting 8 millions in `malloc` overhead.  The number of mallocs you have active counts.
- The second is that when you malloc, you are adding to the total overhead the size of the pointer you use to remember the place malloc gave to you.  This is not accounted in the last place, because you could make only one alloc to store an array, store a million structures contiguous in that array, and reference them with only a pointer.  But this is frequently of no use if you are those pointers to make references between objects, you will need to include all those pointers in the accounting.  If we add this overhead to the one million bytes allocated above you will be incurring in an extra overhead of 4-8million bytes more.  This means you have one million bytes allocated but for maintaining those you need an extra 8 million bytes overhead for you, and 8 milliono bytes overhead hidden into malloc.
- The initial `malloc(1)` in your code can be avoided.  If you read [the documentation of `realloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc), you'll see that `realloc` doesn't need to have a non-null pointer to operate, if you pass a `NULL` pointer to it, it will behave like the initial `malloc()` call, but whith the real amount of storage you need.

The approach in your code is correct, you use a single active malloc all the time, you have decided to grow in steps of `SIZ` (a large `SIZ` is good to minimize the overhead of `malloc` calls, but you will, in the average, incurr in an overhead of not used memory ---memory allocated, but not filled with characters, of around half of the value of `SIZ`, probably more)  As the line length is supposed to follow a poison distribution, the best value for `SIZ` would be the average line length (or better if you use twice that average, for better performance)

Your code, once corrected, would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZ 60 /* assumed an average line length of 30 chars */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *str = NULL; /* <<< use null, don't allocate something you don't need */
    char buf[SIZ];
    /* you don't need to know how many times you repeated the loop */
    int allocd = 0; /* allocated capacity */
    int strsz = 0;  /* filled size */

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) /* the p pointer is not necessary */
    {
        /* grow str */
        int read_chars = strlen(buf);           /* (1 & 2) see below */
        printf("read: [%s]\n", buf);
        int pos_to_cp  = strsz;                 /* (3) we need this at the end
*/
        strsz         += read_chars;
        if (strsz >= allocd) {                  /* need to grow */
            printf("growing from %d to %d\n", allocd, allocd + (int)sizeof buf);
            allocd    += sizeof buf;            /* new size */
            str        = realloc(str, allocd);  /* reallocate to allocd */
        }
        strcpy(str + pos_to_cp, buf);           /* (3) see below */
                                                /* (4) see below */
    }

    printf("ALLOC'D: %i\n", allocd);
    printf("string: %s\n", str);

    free(str);
}
```

(1) The `read_chars` represents the size of the read string, and it will mark the point where we need to copy the string in `buf`.

(2) We don't use a pointer variable here, because as a result of `realloc`, the original pointer can change, so we must evaulate the point of copy once we have the new pointer.

(3) We use pointer arithmetic here to find the point to copy the string.  This way we end copying always (at the same cost) a simple string of size `sizeof buf`, and not appending to a longer and longer string as we iterate on the buffer.

(4) You don't need to check for `if (!p)` because if `p` is `NULL` you never enter in the loop, so the check is useless.

The problem with your program was that your were assuming that the buffer was always filled, so you always needed to grow, which is not true, while `fgets` stops at the receiving of one `\n` character. So the grow of the buffer is not always needed.  I have interspersed some traces in the program, so you can follow it on execution.